# Chrome doesn't open URL automatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Why did this happen? Chrome opens but the URL does not open with the code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        
public class Id {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"); //open browser
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        **driver.get("google.co.in"); //open URL**
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Quadkast" + Keys.ENTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to give http/https protocol along with the url in the get() method**

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            or
driver.get("https://google.com");
```